# Acumatica Styling a specific column in PXGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Im trying to define a Css style for a column in PXGrid.

```
 <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%"
                    TabIndex="100" SkinID="DetailsInTab" StatusField="Availability" SyncPosition="True" Height="473px" OnColumnDataBound="grid_rowBound">


protected void grid_rowBound(object sender, PX.Web.UI.PXGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    Object value = e.Row.Cells["OrigQty"].Value;
    if (value != null && ((Boolean)value) == false)
        e.Row.Style.CssClass = "RedCol";
}
```

Is column styling possible using OnColumnDataBound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create style dynamically as below in page code behind.

In below example, I have modified out-of-box `EP503010` page.

```c
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Style escalated = new Style();
    escalated.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    this.Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(escalated, this, ".CssEscalated");

    Style rowStyle = new Style();
    rowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    this.Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(rowStyle, this, ".CssRowStyle");

    Style cellStyle = new Style();
    cellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
    this.Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(cellStyle, this, ".CssCellStyle");

    Style highlightStyle = new Style();
    highlightStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    this.Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(highlightStyle, this, ".CssHighlightStyle");
}
```

And use that in `OnRowDataBound` event handler of `PXGrid` as below

```c
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, PX.Web.UI.PXGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    EPApprovalProcess.EPOwned item = e.Row.DataItem as EPApprovalProcess.EPOwned;
    if (item == null) return;
    if (item.Escalated == true)
    {
        //For Row - change the Font to Red
        e.Row.Style.CssClass = "CssEscalated";
    }
    else if (item.CuryTotalAmount.HasValue && item.CuryTotalAmount.Value > 10m)
    {
        //For Row - change the background to Red
        e.Row.Style.CssClass = "CssRowStyle";
    }

    //For Specific Column - change the background to Aqua - Whole Column all row.
    e.Row.Cells["Descr"].Style.CssClass = "CssCellStyle";

    //Conditional a specific column cell
    if (item.CuryTotalAmount.HasValue && item.CuryTotalAmount.Value > 10m)
    {
        e.Row.Cells["CuryTotalAmount"].Style.CssClass = "CssHighlightStyle";
    }
}
```

[image]

You can refer out-of-box EP503010.aspx & EP503010.aspx.cs page files.

Comment: How would I apply a CSS style to a whole column.

Comment: @nickivey I have modified the original answer.

Comment: Does anyone know if this same technique can be applied to a screen header cell?  For example, if I want to highlight a cell in a column in AR303000 under the Form column?  I am not very familiar with all of the class definitions you can use in Acumatica.